# Count how many number in a row that have same value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
----------------------
| Name | Location_no |
----------------------
| Joe  |      1      |
| Dan  |      2      |
| Sim  |      2      |
| Jon  |      3      |
| Jim  |      1      |
| Kan  |      2      |
| Tim  |      2      |
| Doe  |      4      |
```

I wanted to count how many Location Number that have 2 or more people lived.

Example like:  Location Number 1 have 2 people lived there.
               Location Number 2 have 4 people lived there.

I don't know How to word this question more clear, comment if you need clearer explanation.

Comment: did you try any query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Location_No, COUNT(*) AS num_lived
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Location_No
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be GROUP BY instead of GROUP_BY?

Comment: @SamuelRobert Typo...try using Stack Overflow on a cell phone and you will appreciate the meaning of frustration.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And that's what I call passion. =p

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
    Location_no, Count(*)
From 
    Table
Group By
    Location_no
Having 
    Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could also use Pivot tables in excel if you are dataset set is small and if you are able to copy to excel. . Pivot tables will help you with better visualizations and good control over data both with sorting and grouping.

Comment: Any other suggestions?? We can also write c++ program for it

Comment: [You should totally drop that and try jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/289429)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query

```
            Select 
                Location_no, Count( distinct name) as [People lived]
            From 
                <tableName> 
            Group By
                Location_no
            Having 
                Count( distinct name) > 1
```